# Looking for the con name of image viewer in Ubuntu 16.04 so I can replace it with my own icon

Tags: 16.04, icons, icon-themes, image-viewers

I am trying to replace the **image viewer** icon with my own. What's the name of image viewer icon in 16.04? From one popular icon theme, I see image viewer icon under 2 entries, namely:

```
x-content-image-dcf.svg
x-content-image-picturecd.svg
```

I am not sure which one I should be replacing. Or, is there any other icon name they are saved under?

Comment: @DavidFoerster I would like to have the icon name, not the location. I can't identify because more than one icon use the same icon file.

Comment: Did you even read the answers to the linked question? You don't need to know the name or location of the current icon to change it. You can just change the `Icon` property of the application starter file to a different name or path that you want to use instead. On top of that that current value of the `Icon` property will give you the (base-)name of the application icon file.

Comment: Since it was marked as a duplicate question, I read the question in the link. :)

Comment: .desktop file says Name=Image Viewer
Comment=Browse and rotate images
TryExec=eog
Exec=eog %U
Icon=eog What should I name the icon ? <b>eog or image viewer </b>

Comment: `Icon=eog`. The base name of the icon files is `eog`. You can find them with `find /path/to/icon-theme -name 'eog.*'`.